# How to fix a function in bash that checks if an RPM package is installed?

Tags: bash, yum

I've written this function:

```
function isInstalled {
if [ rpm -q $1 &> /dev/null ]; then
    echo 'installed';
    return 1;
else
    echo 'not installed';
    return 0;
fi
}
```

But something is wrong. It always returns 0. Even when package is installed. I guess I'm not checking the return signal correctly.

```
[vagrant@centos-7 ~]$ isInstalled wget2
not installed
[vagrant@centos-7 ~]$ isInstalled wget
not installed

[vagrant@centos-7 ~]$ rpm -q wget
wget-1.14-10.el7_0.1.x86_64
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`if [ rpm -q ... &> /dev/null ]` is invalid use of the `[` builtin.
You would see this in the error message if you didn't redirect stderr, like this:

```
if [ rpm -q $1 >/dev/null ]; then
```

Every command you execute has an exit code, so there's no need for wrapping in `[ ... ]`, and it's invalid syntax.

Write it this way:

```
isInstalled() {
    if rpm -q $1 &> /dev/null; then
        echo 'installed';
        return 1;
    else
        echo 'not installed';
        return 0;
    fi
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function should be written as

```
isInstalled() {
    if rpm -q "$1" >/dev/null ; then
        echo "installed"
        return 0
    else
        echo "not installed"
        return 1
    fi
}
```

Notes:

- The [more portable syntax for defining a function](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/73752/17535) is just

  ```
  function_name() {
      …
  }
  ```
- The square brackets `[ ]` are only for [specific kinds of tests](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html), such as for whether a string is empty.  You don't need them to check the exit status of a command.
- Your [redirection syntax](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html) is wrong.
- In shell programming, it is customary to return a zero status for success, and a non-zero status for failure.  Therefore, you should swap your return values.
- You should almost always use double-quotes whenever referencing any variable.  Otherwise, your scripts will break (possibly in security-compromising ways) with unexpected input (such as a <kbd>space</kbd> character in the parameter).

Answer (score 0):

```
function isInstalled {
    rpm -q $1 &> /dev/null;

    if [ $? == 0 ]; then
            return true;
    else
            return false;
    fi
}
```

Test: `if [ isInstalled wget ]; then echo 'installed'; else echo 'not installed'; fi`

Comment: Actually, your test is also invalid, just like the code in your question. See my explanation in my answer